# Error while using raster calculator in model builder

Tags: modelbuilder, spatial-analyst, arcgis-desktop, raster-calculator, rusle

I am trying to use the model builder for the RUSLE Model. Well this is how the model looks like:[image]

So in the raster calculator I have a formula which also involves the rasters generated in the model. This is error which I get .Could anyone tell me what could be going wrong.

[image]

The  formula which I am using in the first raster calculator block is :

Power( ["%FlowAcc_Flow%"] * 10 / 22.1, 0.4) * Power(Sin [" %Slope_Fill%" ]  / 0.09, 1.4) * 1.4

Comment: Can you copy+paste the Error into your question. It's difficult to read.

Comment: Power( ["%FlowAcc_Flow%"] * 10 / 22.1, 0.4) * Power(Sin [" %Slope_Fill%" ] / 0.09, 1.4) * 1.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raster Calculator syntax is tricky.

Using parentheses to separate operators often resolves issues.  And I believe the brackets are unnecessary.  Can you try the following?

```
(Power((("%FlowAcc_Flow%" * 10) / 22.1), 0.4)) * 
(Power((Sin("%Slope_Fill%" / 0.09), 1.4) * 1.4)
```